# Generate a new csv file and order data in ascending numeric order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have written a code that implements the given regex on every postcode that is included in the 'import_data.csv' file. It then generates a new csv file 'failed_validation.csv' which contains all the postcodes where the validation fails. The structure of both files is in the following format:

```
row_id  postcode
134534  AABC 123
243534  AACD 4PQ
534345  QpCD 3DR
... ...
```

Following is my code:

```
import csv
import re

regex = r"(GIR\s0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9]((BR|FY|HA|HD|HG|HR|HS|HX|JE|LD|SM|SR|WC|WN|ZE)[0-9])[0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y](AB|LL|SO)[0-9])|(WC[0-9][A-Z])|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY]))))\s[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})"

codes = []

with open('../import_data.csv','r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in r:

     if not(re.findall(regex, row[1])):
      codes.append([row[0],row[1]])

with open('failed_validation.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerows(codes)
```

The code works fine but what I actually want is the postcodes in the new file need to be ordered as per the row_id, in ascending numeric order. I know how to generate a new file with Python, but I don't know how to order the data inside that file in ascending numeric order.

Comment: As you read, put the processed rows into a list, and sort the list using list.sort or the global function "sorted" before writing out the result.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it and preserve the header row:

```
import csv
import re

regex = r"(GIR\s0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9]((BR|FY|HA|HD|HG|HR|HS|HX|JE|LD|SM|SR|WC|WN|ZE)[0-9])[0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y](AB|LL|SO)[0-9])|(WC[0-9][A-Z])|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY]))))\s[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})"

codes = []
with open('import_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if not re.findall(regex, row[1]):
            codes.append([row[0],row[1]])

with open('failed_validation.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(sorted(codes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your codes list before writing to the file.

```
headers = codes[0]
codes = sorted(codes[1:])
with open('failed_validation.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
  a = csv.writer(fp)
  a.writerow(header)
  a.writerows(codes)
```

Comment: This will break the csv file, because `codes` includes the header row.

Comment: @ekhumoro make sense.